# Can not install kernel headers. Has no installation candidate

Tags: kernel, linux-headers

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10

After that I decided to upgrade to latest kernel as well. But now there is some mismatch between my kernel version and headers.

This image shows that I am using the 5.12.4 kernel. But when trying to update the headers, it says: `linux-headers-generic is already the newest version (5.8.0.53.58)`. I would have expected 5.12.4 to be the newest version?

What did I mess up this time?

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 uses the 5.8 kernel; 5.12.4 is not a supported *groovy* kernel; it is either 3rd party packaged, or a Ubuntu *testing* kernel (you've added yourself as it's not in *stable* repositories).  Ubuntu *hirsute* (21.04) uses the 5.11 kernel, and still not 5.12

Comment: Aaah, alright - so can I downgrade my kernel?

Comment: Reboot into the latest 5.8 kernel, then remove the "foreign" 5.12.4 kernel.